# How to tell TSLint to ignore objects create from a third party library

Tags: javascript, lint, tslint

I am using the 3rd party JS library Openlayers3 and creating objects with it like this:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'foo',
    source: bar,
    ...
});
```

TSLint takes issue with this and I get lots of these errors:

`error: Cannot find name 'ol'`

I'm using a [tslint.json](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/) file (shown below) to manage the TSLint configuration, but it is not clear to me how I tell TSLint to ignore these types of errors?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [true, "spaces"],
    "label-position": true,
    "label-undefined": true,
    "max-line-length": [true, 140],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-key": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unreachable": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "one-line": [true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": true,
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "triple-equals": [true, "allow-null-check"],
    "typedef-whitespace": [true, {
      "call-signature": "nospace",
      "index-signature": "nospace",
      "parameter": "nospace",
      "property-declaration": "nospace",
      "variable-declaration": "nospace"
    }],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ]
  }
}
```